# Moving lights in the sky looks like they were moving coordinated

Tags: star

I was out with a couple friends a night and we looked up to the sky just watching the stars. I noticed what looked like a star moving then told my friends and they saw it too.

After we saw the one moving star we noticed 2 more, it seriously looked like 3 stars just decided to have a meeting. It was the weirdest thing I've ever seen

Answer (score 3):

These are almost certainly satellites. Keep in mind that satellites look like slowly moving stars; well, they move more slowly than meteors do at least! If they were moving somewhat slowly and constantly, and if they had no additional flashing lights and no bright colors, they were definitely satellites. NOSS satellites used to be known for flying in groups of three, but it looks like none of the generations of those triplets are still flying in formation. It looks like the Chinese Yaogan satellites are the only ones flying in triplet formation these days; you probably saw one of them.

See [here](http://www.satobs.org/noss.html).